# Distinct is not working?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

```
  $data = Districts::distinct()->whereRaw('LOWER(district) like ?', [strtolower('%'.$district . '%')])->orWhereRaw('LOWER(region) like ?', [strtolower('%'.$district . '%')])->select('region', 'district')->get();
```

I have this query, but problem is that distinct not working. I get for example three records for same thing. Any suggestion?[image]

Comment: with r code i get again three records

Comment: when i use groupBy('district') i dont get anything, and when i use by id i get same three records

Answer (score 1):

**try to this may i think its could be work**

```
  $data = Districts::select( DB::raw('DISTINCT(district)'))->whereRaw('LOWER(district) like ?', [strtolower('%'.$district . '%')])->orWhereRaw('LOWER(region) like ?', [strtolower('%'.$district . '%')])->get();
```

Comment: Its just i have one problem now i dont get data from region

Answer (score 0):

**try to this may i think its could be work with region**

```
  $data = Districts::select([ DB::raw('DISTINCT(district)'),'region'])->whereRaw('LOWER(district) like ?', [strtolower('%'.$district . '%')])->orWhereRaw('LOWER(region) like ?', [strtolower('%'.$district . '%')])->get();
```

Comment: now again i get three record when i enter name of district

Comment: could you share your table view to understand your problem

Comment: records are distinct so you get more than one record from a district

Comment: but can i do something when use enter distric to get only one and not all of them

Comment: yes because you select only distinct district rather then its records

Comment: you use first in the place of get

Answer (score 0):

**use this to get one**

```
$data = Districts::select([ DB::raw('DISTINCT(district)'),'region'])->whereRaw('LOWER(district) like ?', [strtolower('%'.$district . '%')])->orWhereRaw('LOWER(region) like ?', [strtolower('%'.$district . '%')])->first();
```

Comment: i can not use first because this is suggestion so when user enter something he gets data according to what he enter.